# php form - reload on submit

Tags: php, form-submit, reload

I'm required to edit someone else's code on a website (that person is not reachable) and I don't have much experience on php. At the momment this form redirects to a previous page on submit. I must change it to reload the current page. I've made numerous attempts changing the action field of the form but they all lead to either a blank page or the page it was allready redirecting to. Can someone share a little knowledge here?

```
<div id="tab-general" class="tab-content">
      <form action="<?php echo $action; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td><span class="required">*</span>&nbsp;<?php echo $entry_title; ?></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $title; ?>" name="title" id="title" /><br />
            <?php if ($error_title) { ?>
              <span class="error"><?php echo $error_title; ?></span>
            <?php } ?></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><span class="required">*</span>&nbsp;<?php echo $entry_name; ?></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" name="name" id="name" /><br />
            <?php if ($error_name) { ?>
              <span class="error"><?php echo $error_name; ?></span>
            <?php } ?></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><span class="required">*</span>&nbsp;<?php echo $entry_email; ?></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" name="email" id="email" /><br />
            <?php if ($error_email) { ?>
              <span class="error"><?php echo $error_email; ?></span>
            <?php } ?></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><span class="required">*</span>&nbsp;<?php echo $entry_end_date; ?></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $end_date; ?>" name="end_date" id="end_date" /><br />
            <?php if ($error_end_date) { ?>
              <span class="error"><?php echo $error_end_date; ?></span>
            <?php } ?></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><?php echo $entry_type; ?></td>
            <td><select name="type" id="type" class="type_list">
              <?php if ($type) { ?>
                <option value="1" selected="selected"><?php echo $text_private; ?></option>
                <option value="0"><?php echo $text_public; ?></option>
                <?php } else { ?>
                  <option value="1"><?php echo $text_private; ?></option>
                  <option value="0" selected="selected"><?php echo $text_public; ?></option>
                <?php } ?>
            </select></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><?php echo $entry_status; ?></td>
            <td><select name="status">
            <?php if ($status) { ?>
              <option value="1" selected="selected"><?php echo $text_enabled; ?></option>
              <option value="0"><?php echo $text_disabled; ?></option>
              <?php } else { ?>
                <option value="1"><?php echo $text_enabled; ?></option>
                <option value="0" selected="selected"><?php echo $text_disabled; ?></option>
              <?php } ?>
            </select></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><br /><h2><?php echo $text_invitees; ?></h2></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <table id="attendee" class="list">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <td class="left"><?php echo $entry_att_name; ?></td>
              <td class="right"><?php echo $entry_att_email; ?></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tfoot>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="2"></td>
              <td class="left"><a onclick="addAttendee();" class="button"><?php echo $button_add; ?></a></td>
            </tr>
          </tfoot>
          <?php $attendee_row = 0; ?>
          <?php if ($attendees) { ?>
            <?php foreach ($attendees as $attendee) { ?>
            <tbody id="attendee-row<?php echo $attendee_row; ?>">
              <tr>
                <td class="left"><input type="text" name="attendee[<?php echo $attendee_row; ?>][name]" value="<?php echo $attendee['name']; ?>" size="18" />
                <?php if (isset($error_name_attendee[$attendee_row])) { ?>
                  <span class="error"><?php echo $error_name_attendee[$attendee_row]; ?></span>
                <?php } ?>
                </td>
                <td class="right"><input type="text" name="attendee[<?php echo $attendee_row; ?>][email]" value="<?php echo $attendee['email']; ?>" size="18" />
                <?php if (isset($error_email_attendee[$attendee_row])) { ?>
                  <span class="error"><?php echo $error_email_attendee[$attendee_row]; ?></span>
                <?php } ?>
                </td>
                <td class="left"><a onclick="$('#attendee-row<?php echo $attendee_row; ?>').remove();" class="button"><?php echo $button_remove; ?></a>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          <?php $attendee_row++; ?>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php } ?>
        </table>
      <div class="buttons"><div class="left">
        <a onclick="$('#form').submit();" class="button"><?php echo $button_save; ?></a></div><div class="right"><a onclick="location = '<?php echo $cancel; ?>';" class="button"><?php echo $button_cancel; ?></a>
      </div></div>
  </div>
```

After checking the content of the $action variable it turns out that it holds the link of the current page. It SHOULD reload the page but it doesn't.

example: this is the link

```
localhost/index.php?route=account/projects/editProject&project_id=1&akey=98c27892d1e2a13c0dfb9086539f8275
```

and it is stored in the $action variable. Instead the direction is to the link

```
localhost/index.php?route=account/projects
```

Comment: You have to check the value `$action` variable

Comment: where is $action defined? change that

Comment: it's defined many mane lines of code before...after echoing it i found that it holds the correct link. but for some reason it's not working.

Answer (score 2):

Make Sure your action has path equal to your page path then it will submit your form values and will stay on same page
if this page has path like e.g `/home/index.php`
then

```
<form action="/home/index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form">
```

and if you have get path from your `$action` variable then try `echo $action;` to make sure that you have same path of your current page

Answer (score 0):

The $action variable here om the second row should result in the page that you want to reload.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the form to submit to the current page, simply, remove `action` attribute from your form tag. However, you have to perform a check for a data submision is occured or not to prevent rendering the form or reapeated submitting of the form some thing like the following:

```
<?php if (isset($_POST['title']) && $_POST['title'] != ''): ?>

//Perform form data processing 

<?php else: ?>
// Your form code

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I removed the action attribute and it somehow still redirects to the same page !!

Comment: @Anonymous check your javascript code that performs the submit. Or be sure that the page is not rendered from the cache